# Gradle does not look for custom repos when fetching dependencies of a `sourceControl` module

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I have a blank Gradle 8.2.1 project (made with `gradle init`) and a local repository (which is identical fork of [Nukkit](https://github.com/CloudburstMC/Nukkit)) included with `sourceControl` in *settings.gradle.kts*:

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository(uri("../nukkit")) {
        producesModule("cn.nukkit:nukkit")
    }
}
```

And then it is used as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("cn.nukkit:nukkit") {
        version {
            branch = "inject-plugin"
        }
    }
}
```

Nukkit has own *build.gradle.kts* file, that declares some custom dependency repositories:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://repo.opencollab.dev/maven-releases")
    maven("https://repo.opencollab.dev/maven-snapshots")
}
```

I can build Nukkit separately, but when trying build my blank project with `./gradlew run` some errors occur:

```
...
   > Could not find com.nukkitx.network:raknet:1.6.28-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/nukkitx/network/raknet/1.6.28-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/nukkitx/network/raknet/1.6.28-SNAPSHOT/raknet-1.6.28-SNAPSHOT.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :nukkit
   > Could not find com.nukkitx:natives:1.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/nukkitx/natives/1.0.3/natives-1.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :nukkit
...
```

And so on. Looks like Gradle just ignores Nukkit's custom repositories, so everything dependent on them fail.

How can I fix this problem?

Tried to search on the Internet and changed some settings in Gradle build and settings files of the blank project, including repositories.